# Moving in a few months and not sure what to tell my current employer

Tags: raise, telecommute

I've lived away from my family for almost 10 years now and I want to move close to them when my current lease ends in a few months. Right now I am working as a software engineer and I think my salary is a little low compared to the research I've done for the average salary but I don't mind working at this company. I've been trying to find a new job near where my family lives but I haven't found anything yet.

Today we received our yearly raises and I am not exactly happy with it. I believe I have a good relationship with my company and I am debating going to talk to my boss this week and laying it all on the table; specifically telling them about my impending move, asking for a raise, and the possibility of full time working remotely. We are pretty short staffed and I've been here for 4+ years and have lots of expertise on our product suite so I think I have decent leverage. Wanted to hear some thoughts about this approach.

Comment: All of the things you mention are valid ways to feel. I would avoid the term “leverage” in your chat with your boss, as they might take it negatively.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Be careful about hitting them with so many issues at the same time. Often, that could blunt the impact of your message.

IMHO, I would talk about the raise now, and then follow up with a discussion about remote work later.

That way, you can focus on what you need to do in order to get the raise you feel you deserve. Hopefully, you can get that raise and then in a few months start talking about your desire to work remotely.

If they subsequently say "No" to your remote work request, you can still move to your next job with a higher salary.

Comment: Yeah after talking it over with some poeple and seeing this answer then I think this is the path I'll go down.

Comment: are you planning on moving no matter what?  in which case just explain your plans and tell them what you want and see if you can work out a deal.  if you drip feed issues one after another they will get sick of you complaining

Comment: It’s not the best idea to go with two separate issues and ask for favors, the first might be granted and the second rejected. I would present both issues, so the employer can for example to decide to only offer remote work and know how much they tax it from your raise.

Answer (score 2):

You have three things you can talk to your boss about:

1. Justification for your annual raise.
2. Possibility of working remotely.
3. The possibility of your relocating.

I would avoid including #1 in your discussion. It will muddy the waters and give the impression you are threatening to quit over your compensation. Also, it doesn't appear that these items are separate in your own head. How unhappy are you over your raise? Are you willing to quit over it? If not, then it doesn't belong in this discussion.

Comment: What's wrong with him giving the impression he is threatening to quit over his compensation?

Comment: @Stun Brick, nothing’s wrong with it, if he’s willing to do it. But the question started out with his wanting to move, followed with (how I read it) additional things he’s unhappy with, including his raise.